# MOSFET selection for 5V LED Circuit

Tags: mosfet

This is a follow up question to my previous one,([Transistor selection for 5V LED circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81569/transistor-selection-for-5v-led-circuit)) where I was (kindly) guided to using a MOSFET to switch on this circuit.

My intention to switch this circuit on/off using a capacitive sensor IC such as this: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/42/iqs904_datasheet-8785.pdf

At moment I'm still testing on the breadboard.  In the diagram below I'v replaced the IC with a simple switch+resistor to represent the output of Pin 3 (presumed to be 3~5 mA @ 5v) The LEDs are 3.6v @ 20mA

The circuit now looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwkdCJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm new to MOSFETS (and actually electronics). From a quick look around it looks like a [2N7002K](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/2N7002K-102052.pdf) would work.

Is this the correct choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go over the main specs of the MOSFET...

Drain-Source Voltage (Vdss)=60v.  You will be subjecting it to 5v, so you're good!

Gate-Source Voltage (Vgss)=20v.  You're at 5v, so good.

Drain Current (Id)=300 mA continuous.  You are at 100 mA (20 mA for each of the 5 LED's).  Good!

Gate Threshold Voltage (Vgs(th))=1.0-2.5v.  You'll be driving the gate with either 0.0v or 5.0v, so here again you are good.

I ignored some of the more esoteric specs, which could come into play if you were driving an inductive load like a motor or relay, or needing to have fast switching or high-frequency switching.  But for turning some LEDs on or off, this MOSFET will be just fine.